# Download a file given an url to a restricted area and a cookie container

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a queue of jobs in an ASP.NET CORE Application. Each of the files are in a restricted area and I have to Login first, thats why I use a Cookie Container for my download request.

The Job is logging into a platform and then starts to download the file, given an URL and a Cookie Container from the Login.

The download method is looking like this and has a Func which reports the progress in 5 % steps:

```
public async Task DownloadFile(string url, string destination, Func<int, Task> reportStatus)
{
        await reportStatus(0);

        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        request.CookieContainer = m_cookieContainer;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
        var requestStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(requestStream))
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(destination))
            {
                const int bufferSize = 2048;
                byte[] bytes;
                short oldPercentage = 4;
                long bytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = reader.ReadBytes(bufferSize);
                    await fileStream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                    bytesRead += bytes.Length;

                    var percentage = (short)(bytesRead * 100 / response.ContentLength);
                    if (oldPercentage < percentage)
                    {
                        await reportStatus(percentage);
                        oldPercentage = (short)(oldPercentage + 5);
                    }
                } while (bytes.Length != 0);
            }
        }

        await reportStatus(100);
}
```

Small problems I am currently facing:

- Download speed feels quite slow in comparison to my internet connection.
- I was wondering if there are better ways downloading a file from a restricted area using .NET Core functionality.

Comment: i think parameter `jobId` is useless here

Comment: maybe speed will increase if you write all bytes to file once in the end

Comment: For simplicity I have made the source code a bit smaller, thats why Job id isn't used. I have removed it from the code now.

Comment: @Disappointed memory usage will also then increase

Comment: I have rolled back your edit as it would invalidate existing answers, in accordance with our policy.See [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 7):

You mentioned that the download is slower than you'd expect, I'll focus on just that for a quick review.

Look at your code here:

> ```
> var percentage = (short)(bytesRead * 100 / response.ContentLength);
> if (oldPercentage < percentage)
> {
>     await reportStatus(percentage);
>     oldPercentage = (short)(oldPercentage + 5);
> }
> ```

Can you see why that might be slowing down your download?

> ```
> await reportStatus(percentage);
> ```

You're waiting for the task reporting the status to finish before reading the rest of the stream! What if `reportStatus` were logging the progress to a database or doing something else really time consuming?

I think you should just execute the callback and not care when/how it finishes:

```
reportStatus(percentage); // Don't wait
```

---

Oh and `oldPercentage` is really confusing when you scan the code... I'd rename it to something like `reportingThreshold`.

```
if (percentage > reportingThreshold)
{
     reportStatus(percentage);
     reportingThreshold = (short)(reportingThreshold+ 5);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that right after I posted this question. It actually is a bottleneck, because I do write to the Job database everytime I report the progress. However it is only updated every 5 %, so it can't be the main problem here when it comes to big files (e.g. 100 MB downloading with a 50mbit connection). Anyway, thanks I will try to implement your change :) I will get into some threading issues though. Because who will guarantee that 5 % DB update is committed before a 10 % DB update :)

Comment: @Jannik - Add your updates to a queue in `reportProgress` and process the queue separately to maintain the order. I can assure you that the latency on a DB call 20 times during a download will have a noticeable effect on speed.

Answer (score 5):

As a matter of fact you should use the [`IProgress<T>` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298(v=vs.110).aspx) for reporting progress that

> Defines a provider for progress updates.

With it you wouldn't be tempted to `await` it because the [`Report` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193864(v=vs.110).aspx) is `void`.

Example:

```
public async Task DownloadFile(string url, string destination, IProgress<int> progress)
{
   ..
   progress.Report(percentage);
   ..
}
```

See also [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/)